# iOSのパスワードの自動入力(他サイト)ができない

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Twitchのユーザー名とパスワードを自動でiCloudパスワード、他のパスワードマネージャーから自動で入力候補を出したいのですが、入力候補が出てくれません。

[image]

```swift
struct LoginView: View {
  @State var userName: String = ""
  @State var password: String = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    Form() {
      TextField("UserName", text: $userName)
        .textContentType(.username)
        .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
      
      SecureField("Password", text: $password)
        .textContentType(.password)
      
      Button(action: {
        
      }, label: {
        Text("Login")
      })
    }
  }
}
```

### 設定

- Bundle Identifier: `K6AZ33YM5B.tv.twitch`
  https://www.twitch.tv/.well-known/apple-app-site-associationに載っているものをテスト的に使用(おそらくこのファイルに載っていないものは認可されないので)
- Capabilities

  - Associated Domain

    - webcredentials:[www.twitch.tv](http://www.twitch.tv)
    - applinks:[www.twitch.tv](http://www.twitch.tv)
    - activitycontinuation:[www.twitch.tv](http://www.twitch.tv)
    - appclips:[www.twitch.tv](http://www.twitch.tv)
  - AutoFill Credential Provider

    - true

Comment: `App ID Prefix`がどうしても異なってしまうので、所有していないサイトのパスワードの自動入力は不可能ということですかね？

Comment: > 所有していないサイトのパスワードの自動入力は不可能
はい。そういうことです。どのアプリでも同じようにできたらドメインと関連付けている意味がなくなってしまいますので。

Comment: サードパーティ製のアプリを作った際に、自動入力できればなと思ったのですが、できないのですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: まあちょっと手順が増えるだけで鍵マークを押して自分で選ぶことはできるのでそんなに問題ないと思いますよ。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`App ID Prefix`の関係でサイト所有者でないと出来ないということがわかりました。